# Update a controller variable with ajax in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to update a variable in my view after clicking on a table row.  Right now I have a javascript function:

```
  $("#myTable tr").click(function(){

      var rowData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
          return $(this).text();
      }).get();

      var id = $.trim(rowData[0]);

      $.ajax({
              ...
      });

  })
```

I want to pass the variable "id" to the controller so that it can update in my view.  I don't know what would go inside the ajax call.  I also don't know what would go inside the controller I know that I need to use a respond_to but not sure what else.

Comment: you can fire an ajax request which sends data to controller method, manipulate it in controller action and through js, it will update your view. I have answered it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709797/6166821

Answer (score 0):

you have to write this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <%= path_of_controller_action %>,
    data: { data what you want to send },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $form.find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
      $form.find('.ajax-in-progress').removeClass('hidden');
      return Daisy.ajax_loader(true, 'waiting', 'small');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      return location.reload();
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("Oops! An error occurred, please try again");
      return console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

I f you want to some extra you should use [DataTable Ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)